# colors with compound adjectives

Tags: adjectives, hyphens, compounds

I've read that if two colors hyphenated for singular type that means it is combination colors. If not, then it has part colors like:

> A1. *A blue-green shirt* is turquoise.
>   A2. *A blue and green shirt* is one which has parts that are blue and parts green.

but if we are talking about plural, then that doesn't mean combination, like:

> B1. *She has only blue and green shoes*. Means: that all of the person’s shoes are either blue or green
>   B2. *She has only blue-and-green shoes* Means: that the person’s shoe collection consists only of shoes in which each pair is blue
>       and green.

Same here:

> C1. *Yellow, pink, and red flowers* refers to flowers colored yellow, pink, or red.
>   C2. Whereas *yellow-pink-and-red flowers* denotes tricolored flowers.

Which you prefer A1-2 or B1-2 OR C1-2

Comment: The A rules and the B rules look correct, but the C rules are confusing.  I can't imagine ever writing "yellow-pink-and-red flowers".  I don't think there is a single unambiguous way to refer to tricolored things like that.

Comment: totally agree,but the essential question is>>why B2 different than A1

Comment: A1 are combination colors {turquoise}.. B2 aren't ,, both of them are hyphenated

Comment: *Yellow-pink-and-red flowers* seems very wrong to me for a tricoloured flower. For that, omit the *and*: *yellow-pink-red flowers*.

Comment: Using hyphenated words to describe colors is most useful when the colors are not ones for which we already have a name.  So *blue-green* is more easily read and more accurately called *aqua* or *teal*.  Same for *pink-red* which would better be called *magenta* or *fuchsia*.  I would use the hyphenated form for *green-brown* or *blue-orange*.

Comment: *She has only blue-green shoes.*  Works for plurals too.

Answer (score 1):

These rules seem overly prescriptive.

We do sometimes use the two colour names to indicate an intermediate colour. So "A blue-green shirt" is a turquoise.

The expression "She has only blue and green shoes" in ambiguous. It could mean that she has some blue and some green shoes, or it could mean all her shoes are patterned blue and green. Using hyphens can reduce that ambiguity in written English. But if a completely unambiguous sentence is required, then you would have to rephrase.

The example with flowers is similarly ambiguous. If it matters, then the expression could be rephrased. The hyphenated form is ugly and difficult to say, so wouldn't be used in practice. Normally it doesn't matter much if the flowers are individually red, yellow and pink, or pattern with red, yellow and pink, so the ambiguity can be allowed to remain.

Answer (score 0):

phrases with multiple hyphens appear unwieldy.  "yellow-pink-and-red flowers" would be uncommon; most people would describe "flowers that have swirls of yellow, pink, and red" rather than using the multiple hyphens.  It is a longer description, but easier to read and say.

But, in general, those rules are grammatically correct.

Comment: yeah you are totally right, but it has a different meaning when it is hyphenated and when not, I am afraid it would come in my exams

Comment: I have no problem with A1.2 but with B,C1.2